# How to keep the styles of webpage the same

Tags: html, css

I want to know if there is a way to create a form that will keep all styles of a webpage, while changing the content of the content of the page. Ex: When you submit a question to Stackoverflow, it keeps the all stylistic parts of the page, i.e. Header and sidebars, while changing the title and majority of page's content. Also if you can would a server-side languange, such as php, be best or would a web-side languange, such as Javascript, be best

Comment: Neither PHP, nor JS... this is done using [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).

Answer (score 1):

Style sheets (CSS) exist for exactly this task. Ideally, the HTML for a page contains only its content, while style sheets contain all presentation (the "look"/"format" of the page). Reusing the same style sheet(s) on most or all pages results in a consistent look across an entire website.

See http://www.w3schools.com/css/ for more general information and tutorials.

**Edit** If you're referring more to reusing "structural" markup across pages, that is accomplished using a template engine. Using templates things like primary navigation, sidebars, etc. can be defined in one file and used on any page that extends the base template. Many web frameworks have a template engine built-in ([Django, for example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/) has one I personally use and like).

Answer (score 1):

This is handled using **[CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)**. Basically, websites are built using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

- HTML builds the structure of the website. It creates the basic building blocks of the site.
- CSS takes care of how the website looks. It stylizes the building blocks.
- JavaScript takes care of the functionality of the website. It can manipulate the building blocks in order to make something happen.

In order to maintain the same look of certain elements on a website, it is best to create a so called **pattern library**. A pattern library is a document consisting of pieces of code—these pieces can be reused throughout the website in order to maintain consistence. In this document, you specify the formatting of the essential elements (headings, body text, blockquotes, buttons, form elements etc. (Pattern libraries are sometimes also referred to as "*style guides*", however, style guides are usually visual documents, while pattern libraries are consisting of pieces of code.)

Of course you can specify the look of your website without using a pattern library, however, it might get a bit harder to maintain the same style throughout the whole website or keep the styling the same when handing the project over to another developer.

You can read more about pattern libraries in [this post](http://www.creativebloq.com/netmag/why-you-should-manage-your-css-pattern-libraries-71412346) if you feel like it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by css also you can devide the page into many files
such as putting the header in another page (header.html) and include it in the main page using php (include_once('header.html'))